# Django templates - Image from media_root rendered in homepage, but not other pages

Tags: django, image, django-templates, render

I have an image that renders on my homepage, but it doesn't on a different page using the same code. I figure the problem may be the difference my url path maybe? It's the only difference I can find. When I inspect each element, this is what I see:

> Working image: /event/image.png
>
> Broken Image: /event/media/image.png

I'm rendering the image like this in my template:

```
        <img src="media/{{event.image}}" class="img-responsive" />
```

My model is just aa model.Image field and here are is my view for the Broken image page:

```
def event(request, product_id):
    event = get_object_or_404(Event, id=product_id)

    image = event.image
    context = {'event':event, 'image':image}
    template = 'tourney.html'
    return render(request, template, context)
```

In my terminal, it says image not found. So how can I change my settings so that it looks in the right directory no matter which path I'm in? Here are my media settings:

```
if DEBUG:
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static', 'static-only')
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static', 'media')
    STATICFILES_DIRS = (
        os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static', 'static'),
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a leading slash: "/media/...".

However, even better would be to use the built-in property that gives you the full URL including MEDIA_URL:

```
<img src="{{ event.image.url }}" class="img-responsive">
```

Comment: I see! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Instead of building url by yourself, like `media/{{event.image}}`, let Django do that job for you:

```
    <img src="{{ event.image.url }}" class="img-responsive" />
```

That way, Django will create proper URL, using `MEDIA_URL` from your settings. Be aware that your web server configuration must match that and serve images from `MEDIA_ROOT` on `MEDIA_URL`

Comment: Thank you also for a timely answer!